# Resize div according to the browser size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a div to resize only when the screen size reaches to a certain size. I am using jQuery.

```
<script>
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(screenwidth);
    if(screenwidth>=992){
        $("main").css("width","500px");
        console.log($("main").width());
    }
    if(screenwidth<992 && screenwidth>=650){
        $("main").css("width","300px");
         console.log($("main").width());
    }
</script>
```

Problem: The problem is that when the screenwidth goes less than 992px it doesn't resize to 300px but I have to refresh the browser to make it effective. 
Anyway to make it dynamic and responsive.

Comment: What about putting it into a function and using a setInterval() refresh it every 500ms?

Comment: You need to add an event listener on the window's resize -- and then run your code from there.  As it is written now, it will only resize once (on load) but will not be called again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize (here's a link to jQuery's resize method: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ )

Comment: Or you can use CSS media queries to adjust the div size based off of the dimensions of the site. (my personal recommendation, but whichever you feel the most comfortable with)

Answer (score 2):

You can use @media in css

```
@media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 650px) { 
  main {width: 300px;} 
}
```

And specify the value 500px in default

Answer (score 0):

You could look into media queries, I think this will solve your problems.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a function to the "onresize" event:

```js
function resize() {
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(screenwidth);
    if(screenwidth>=992){
        $("main").css("width","500px");
        console.log($("main").width());
    }
    if(screenwidth<992 && screenwidth>=650){
        $("main").css("width","300px");
         console.log($("main").width());
    }
}
resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onresize="resize()">
  <main></main>
</body>
```